# Address of array elements c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointer arithmetics in C++ uses sizeof(type) incremention instead of byte incremention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037503/pointer-arithmetics-in-c-uses-sizeoftype-incremention-instead-of-byte-increm)

Tried to find the answer but could not.
I have the following c++ code:

```
struct A {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint16_t c;
}

int main() {
    uint16_t * B = new uint16_t[5000];
    for (int i=0;i<5000;i++)
        B[i] = i;

    uint16_t * D = &B[500]+sizeof(A);
}
```

Question is: why *D=512 after this? When I debug sizeof(A) = 6 as it should be. Yet I add to memory address of B[500] the size of A it adds 12 instead of 6.
I am working with memory address still there is a multiplication and I cannot figure out why it is so.

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: http://ideone.com/UGxPPK it prints 506

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a compiler bug if `sizeof(A)` is indeed 6.

```
&B[500] + 6 == &B[506]
```

and thus `*D` ought to be 506 then. And it is when I compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct A {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint16_t c;
};

int main() {
    uint16_t * B = new uint16_t[5000];
    for (int i=0;i<5000;i++)
        B[i] = i;

    uint16_t * D = &B[500]+sizeof(A);
    std::cout << (*D) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with g++-4.7.1 or clang++-3.1.

Comment: Agreed, I thought something was fishy with the other answers.

Comment: What if his debug build and his release build have different alignment requirements in structs? This looks like when OP runs his code, the members of the struct are 32-bit aligned.

Comment: @us2012 the op said that `sizeof(A)` is 6, in which case it is a bug in the compiler. If, for alignment, the size is `12`, then yes, it should print 512.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore What I'm thinking is: OP is debugging on his PC (targetting the PC with the compiler), but running the code on a microcontroller (Arduino or similar, targeting this with the compiler), i.e. he's looking up `sizeof` on one system and running his code on another one.

Comment: @us2012 That could be. Although having a 32-bit alignment requirement for a `struct` containing only `uint16_t` would be odd and pointless.

Comment: OK guys. One more: If I add 1 to &B[500] it will be 502.

Comment: @Teddy If you assign `D = &B[500] + 1;`? I have a hard time believing that a compiler could be that borken. What's the exact compiler version you're using?

Comment: OK guys. One more: If I add 1 to &B[500] it will be 502. So the following code:
    uint16_t * val = &A[500];
    std::cout << "VALS:" << val << "\t" << val + 1 << "\n\n";

Returns 0x971ce7c and 0x971ce7e 
Why the increment of two?

Comment: @Teddy The increment of two for `val + 1` is because `sizeof(uint16_t)` is 2. So adding one to a `uint16_t*` advances it by two bytes. That is the address of `B[501]`, though.

Comment: @Daniel: g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)

Comment: @Teddy So, did you print out memory addresses all the time and never the value `D` points to?

Comment: I printed out the value of course. And it is OK when I add 1. Seems the trouble comes when I try to use the sizeof struct as it multiplies with the size of uint16_t causing trouble to me. I think I understand now. Who should I vote up?

Comment: "It's a compiler bug if sizeof(A) is indeed 6" Why? Should it be rounded up to 8?

Comment: @Teddy No. Well, the compiler may add padding to the `struct` if it likes it four-byte aligned. But then the size would not be 6. **If the size is 6**, then `&B[500] + sizeof(A)` **must** be `&B[506]`, otherwise it's a compiler bug.

Comment: As said it is 512. Seems sizeof value is converted to uint16* so it is multiplied by two. (sizeof does return 6 but when I add to &B[500] it becomes 512).

Comment: @Teddy `sizeof(A)` is multiplied with `sizeof(uint16_t)` under the hood to get the number of bytes that the pointer should be advanced by. But that would take you to `&B[506]`. If you get 512 from printing `*D`, that's plain wrong (assuming the reasonable `sizeof(A) == 6`). I wouldn't expect any compiler to get such a fundamental thing wrong, but if that's what you got, it happened.